# Having trouble getting number of comments for each post on my website

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

So I'm making a social network and I need to display the number of comments below each post before a user expands the comment area. I'm trying to create a view where I can select data easily. I have a "messages" table containing each post and a column "related_id" indicating if that message is a comment to a parent message.

My first step was to build a subquery containing the id of the message and the number of comments. Then I will do a left join from the "messages" table with the "num_ans" column mentioning the number of replies for each parent post.

One problem I ran into is that I'm forced to do a group by in my second query and I don't understand why. All I want is to append the "num_ans" column to each row of the "messages" table. But my query returns 1 for every num_ans. One positive thing: when the id is not in the subquery, then it is zero which is fine.

I just want a "messages" table with a number of replies column "num_ans". What am I doing wrong?

```sql
SELECT a.*, b.count as num_ans
FROM "messages.dev" a 
left outer join 
(
  select related_id, count(*) as num_ans
from "messages.dev"
where related_id is not null
group by related_id
order by num_ans desc
) as b
on a.id=b.related_id 
where a.related_id is null
-- don't understand this group by
group by a.id, a.created_at, a.related_id, a.author, a.content, a.num_like, a.num_impr, a.share_id
--
order by num_ans desc, created_at
```

Comment: As messages is a table and dev a column, then you it seems you have a syntax error and need to remove the quotation marks.

Comment: Try: SELECT
  a.*,
  b.count as num_ans
FROM
  messages.dev a
  left outer join (
    select
      related_id,
      count(*) as num_ans
    from
      messages.dev
    where
      related_id is not null
    group by
      related_id
    order by
      num_ans desc
  ) as b on a.id = b.related_id
order by
  num_ans desc,
  created_at

Comment: Failed to run sql query: column "a.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to join at all if you just need the count.

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  (select count(*) from "messages.dev" b where b.related_id = a.id)::int as num_ans
FROM "messages.dev" a
where a.related_id is null
order by a.num_ans desc, a.created_at;
```